# Why does my axios post request to nodemailer result in a 431 (Request Header Fields Too Large)?

Tags: reactjs, express, google-chrome, axios, nodemailer

I have a single page react portfolio I'm working on and wanted to add a contact form using nodemailer but receiving the 431 (Request Header Fields Too Large) error when my axios request attempts to run.  The server is running using `concurrently` so both the front and backend are running at the same time.  Not sure what else to try, so if someone has any suggestions, that would be fantastic!

**Things I've tried:** Cleared my google chrome cache, cookies, & history, tried incognito mode, updated my node to the latest version, added max-http-header-size, tried different browsers.

**Errors:**

- POST http://localhost:3000/send 431 (Request Header Fields Too
  Large)
- Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status
  code 431

Here is my initial post request using axios which it won't go past:

```
const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    axios
      .post("http://localhost:3000/send", {
        name: content.firstName + " " + content.lastName,
        email: content.email,
        message: content.message,
      })
      .then((response) => {
        if (response.data.msg === "success") {
          alert("Message Sent");
          resetForm();
        } else if (response.data.msg === "fail") {
          alert("Message failed to send");
        }
      });
  };
```

Comment: Have you tried removing browsers from the equation entirely? I would copy the request headers and drop the request into curl and see what happens.

Comment: I haven't used curl but looked it up and used curl -i http://localhost:3000/send and got the 431 notice again.  How would I drop the request into curl exactly?  Also, I checked it out in Postman and got 431 as well.